# Accessing years-long discussions in Google Hangouts in the future, can I also make an off-line backup?

Tags: google-hangouts, backup, google-hangouts-chat

[With the destruction of Album Archives, where will all of the photos from a Hangouts be stored?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126479/224799) and answers therein address some aspects of google hangouts "going away" over time.

> Google Hangouts is slowly getting "discontinued" as well.

While there are several links to possible futures, I'd like to ask about having access to *historical chats* in Google Hangouts; the text and images interspersed within it.

Will I likely always be able to access historical chats in some way? Right now I can search for bits I remember through keyword search in Gmail, and from a browser scroll backwards from now in a hangouts tab, but will I always be able to do this in the future?

**note:** I think that [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126361/224799) may be saying "yes" but I'm not 100% certain.

Is there some way that I can backup the text of a Hangouts chat *offline*, ideally with interspersed images intact?

Comment: Does this answer your question [How do I get a transcript of my Google hangout chat?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45304/88163) ?

Comment: @Rubén thanks for that! I will work through those answers today. While they are circa 2013-2015, [this comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45304/how-do-i-get-a-transcript-of-my-google-hangout-chat#comment127033_78782) is current and that looks quite promising! :-)